# python tkinter listbox to be update on each button click

Tags: tkinter

Below is the piece of code where i am trying to search a pattern in text box and then getting the result in listbox. On clicking each line in listbox , it will show the text box.

I am facing one issue, each time i click on the Search button, it creates a new listbox instead of updating the parent listbox. How can i achieve this. Please advise.

```
import pysftp
import sys
import spur
import paramiko
from Tkinter import *



message =""


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname', username='user', password='password')



root = Tk()


L1 = Label(root, text="Pattern")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)

E1.pack(side = LEFT)

def OnDouble(event):
        master = Tk()
        widget = event.widget
        selection=widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])
        #print "selection:", selection, ": '%s'" % value
        command="~/Format.sh "+ value
        ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        data = ssh_stdout.readlines()
        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
        yscrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
        xscrollbar.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill=X )
        #print data
        text = Text(master, width=100,yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set)
        for line in data:
         text.insert(INSERT, line)
        text.insert(END, "Bye Bye.....")
        text.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)
        xscrollbar.config( command = text.xview)
        yscrollbar.config( command = text.yview)



def callback():
    message= E1.get()
    command="~/IndexSearch_py.sh "+ message
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)


    data = ssh_stdout.readlines()
    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    yscrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )
    xscrollbar.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill=X )

    mylist = Listbox(root, width=80,yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand = xscrollbar.set )
    length=len(data);
    for i in range(length):
     mylist.insert(END, data[i])
    print mylist.size()




    mylist.bind("<Double-Button-1>", OnDouble)
    mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )

    xscrollbar.config( command = mylist.xview)
    yscrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview)




b = Button(root, text="Search", width=20, command=callback)
b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: You are creating the listbox in the callback, so of course it's going to create a new listbox every time it is called. As a general rule, don't create widgets in callbacks.

Comment: thanks Bryan for response. So if i would create widgets outside, then should i be taking some global variable or list to keep data updating in my listbox? otherwise is there any other option to keep data updated on each click .

Comment: You should create the listbox once, and then on each event you can delete everything and re-add everything, or you can compute what the differences are and just add or remove the things that changed.

Comment: Thanks Bryan!! It worked for me as you suggested...